# Phoenix 1.4 How to alias Routes.page_path in a Plug

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, plug

I've tried a couple different iterations but I keep getting this error when compiling:

```
Routes.session_path/2 is undefined (module Routes is not available)
```

My Code:

```ex
defmodule Blackbook.Plugs.RequireAuth do
    import Plug.Conn
    import Phoenix.Controller
    alias Blackbook.Router.Helpers, as: Routes

    def init(_params) do
    end

    def call(conn, _params) do
        if conn.assigns[:current_user] do
            conn
        else
            conn
            |> put_flash(:error, "You must be logged in.")
            |> redirect(to: Routes.session_path(conn, :new))
            |> halt()
        end
    end
end
```

It's a little different in Phoenix 1.4, tried referring to documentation here https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Router.html but still no luck.

Comment: Please mark  @Sheharyar's answer as correct, if it was useful for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using [phoenix-framework](/questions/tagged/phoenix-framework), it creates a separate `YourAppWeb` namespace for web-related modules by default. In your case, I believe it's just a typo and it should be this:

```ex
alias BlackbookWeb.Router.Helpers, as: Routes
```

<sup>*(Note the `Web` part)*</sup>